# Oracle APEX - set select list selected value based on page item

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a select list on a page and its source set to a sql query:

```
SELECT t.name d,t.id   r
FROM   Table1 t
WHERE  t.status = 'New'
AND( t.id = TO_NUMBER(:P3_MY_ID)
OR :P3_MY_ID IS NULL)
ORDER BY 1
```

And I see mt P3_MY_ID set in session but the value in my select list is not selected. Can anyone help?

The value of P3_MY_ID is getting set in pre-render before regions

Comment: From what I understand, you are trying to have a value selected by default in your select list ? (That value being the ID in `P3_MY_ID`)
Or you want to select a value in your select list by changing `P3_MY_ID` ?

Comment: I want to select a value in the select list when P3_MY_ID is changed

Answer (score 2):

List of Values properties group contains the **Cascading LOV Parent Item(s)** - put `P3_MY_ID` in there.

Also, make sure that query you wrote actually *returns* something (using the `P3_MY_ID` value you use in Apex) when executed in SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, TOAD or whichever tool you use.

Comment: I did that but nothing changed - the value still does not get selected. I ran the query in Toad and it does return a value

Comment: Hm, strange ... looks like a trivial problem. Did you try to run the page in debug mode and view the results afterwards?

Comment: yes, I did. i am just not sure what to look for. The P3_MY_ID gets set in pre-render before the select list gets loaded

Comment: Right; which means that the select list *should* see it, but somehow it doesn't ...

Comment: I figured it out - I set the value of the select list to that page item via javascript in Page Load event

Comment: OK, I'm glad you fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

to set the value of a select list you need to create a dynamic action set the event to when change>selection type page item> your item P3_MY_ID.
set the true action to set value> set type sql statment> your query> affected element> type item> your select list